# Как создать функцию для записи в файлы (txt, csv, json)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Пишу функцию для записи фаила json Файл создается, но пустой. код:

```
def write_file():
    with open('file_json.json', "w", encoding="utf-8") as file_json:
        file_json = create_randome_dict_json_file()
        data = json.dumps(file_json)
    return data
print(generate_and_write_file())
```

Ранее я сгенерировал: `таблицу для записи в файл csv (create_random_list_csv()), словарь для записи в файл json (create_randome_dict_json_file()) строку для записи в файл txt (create_randome_txt_data())` Мне нужно написать функцию, например write_file которая принимает один параметр - полный путь к файлу. В зависимости от расширения файла (txt, csv, json) сгенерировать данные для записи и записать в данный файл. Если расширение не соответствует заданным, то вывести текст "Unsupported file format"

Вопрос: как его наполнить и может можно сделать все 1 функцией, для всех файлов?

Comment: не очень понятен вопрос: то записывать json, то что-то из txt, csv, json... и что значит "расширение не соответствует заданным"? дайте больше конкретика и, возможно, код всех фукций из текста

Comment: как я понял, нужно записать 3 функции, которые ранее были созданы во все txt, csv, json, если не возможно этого сделать вывести сообщение "Unsupported file format"

Comment: а где происходит "сгенерировать данные для записи"?

Comment: в новой функции, вот как ее правильно создать?

Comment: @Stud200891, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы документацию внимательно читали?
   json.dumps никоим образом не пишет в файл. А служит лишь для конвертации объекта Python в строку json.

Запись в json-файл выполняется методом json.dump:

```
with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data, write_file)
```

Ну а то, что file_json вы используете сначала как идентификатор объекта а потом вообще переопределяете непонятно как - это отдельный вопрос.

2. *Функцию, например write_file*

Непонятно в чем вопрос. Объединить в одну функцию можно. Это функция должна псоледовательно делать следующее: Читать данные, парсить и проверяеть расширение. В зависимости от результата вызывать один из трех ваших генераторов и соответственно -  одну из трех разных функций записи.

Comment: а как это правильно сделать?

Comment: На первый вопрос - ясно же написано, как сделать. Что в нем осталось вам непонятно? Только конкретно. На второй вопрос - тоже написана последовательность шагов вашей программы. Надеюсь, создавать функции умеете? Данные распрарсить можно методом split(). Проверка - тривиальна -  оператор if и проверка на равенство строк. В зависимости от ответа вызов вашей функции генерации и функции записи в файл соответствующего формата. Если остались еще вопросы - задавайте.  Что значит ваше "правильно" - я не понял.